# What is the algorithm to update ELO ratings for a two-player board game?

Tags: algorithm

Assume a two-player board game match just finished between player1 and player2. We know the ratings of player1, player2 before the match, and the result of the match (player1 wins, player2 wins, or draw). Is there  a simple algorithm that can calculate the updated ELO rating of the two players after the match? Or are the updated elo ratings depend on more information that that?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system#Mathematical_details) has you covered.

Comment: There's more than one way to update ELO scores, so an answer to your question would be more of an essay on the various ideas and what advantages and disadvantages they have in various situations. So this doesn't make a good stackoverflow question, where questions are narrow enough that answers are clearly right or clearly wrong. As @Ohjeah suggests, you should look at external resources on ELO, and come back and ask a question here if you have a more specific problem.